# pandas iterrows() skipping specified row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm running a loop in my code that pulls SQL queries from an excel sheet saved on my computer and then executes that query. Each time the query is done running, it goes to the next row and does this until there are no more queries. However, i want to add where the user can skip a certain row if they would like (for run time purposes). Here's what my loop looks like right now:

```
    selected_rows = ['1', '2', '4', '5']

    for index, row in loop_file.iterrows():
        print('run(): ' + row['Name'])
        query = row['Logic']
        inner_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
        if inner_df.empty:
            continue
        inner_df['project_id'] = pr_id
        inner_df['logic_name'] = row['Name']
        outer_df = pd.concat([outer_df, inner_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

    clean_up = 'if object_id ('tempdb..#table') is not null drop table #table'

    cursor.execute(clean_up)

    return outer_df
```

So selected_rows would be the rows that the user selected from the UI, skipping query 3. What's the most effective way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thanks for any pointers or tips!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `selected_rows` as an index for the dataframe.

Like so:

```
# this is assumed to be the index
    selected_rows = [1, 2, 4, 5]
# filter to only contain the selected indices
filtered = loop_file[selected_rows]

# proceed as previously
for index, row in filtered.iterrows():
    print('run(): ' + row['Name'])
    query = row['Logic']
    inner_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    if inner_df.empty:
        continue
    inner_df['project_id'] = pr_id
    inner_df['logic_name'] = row['Name']
    outer_df = pd.concat([outer_df, inner_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

clean_up = 'if object_id ('tempdb..#table') is not null drop table #table'

cursor.execute(clean_up)

return outer_df
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can add that condition to skip as an `if` statement inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know all the details, I'll do my best to edit your code to solve the problem in the simplest way.

```
selected_rows = ['1', '2', '4', '5']

for index in range(len(loop_file)):
    if str(index) in selected_rows:
        row = loop_file.iloc[index]
        print('run_toleau(): ' + row['Name'])
        query = row['Logic']
        inner_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
        if inner_df.empty:
            continue
        inner_df['project_id'] = pr_id
        inner_df['logic_name'] = row['Name']
        outer_df = pd.concat([outer_df, inner_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

clean_up = 'if object_id ('tempdb..#toleau') is not null drop table #toleau'

cursor.execute(clean_up)

return outer_df
```

As a note, it is best to avoid iterrows() if possible if performance is at all a concern.

Comment: Hi Garrett, thanks for the response. I am trying to use your for loop but i seem to be getting a the following error: "None of [Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,]         dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]". is this because i dont have these indexes specified in the file, would that be an issue?

Comment: You may want to use row = loop_file.loc[index] depending on what your df looks like or possibly index+1 to start at 1.